# Ajax call not appending to DisplayFor and sending null value back to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my ASP MVC view, we use an account number to pull the last name from a SQL table. Once the user enters the account number and tabs out of the field, an Ajax call is sent back to the server and is supposed to input the value into a `DisplayFor` field. However, this code only works if I give the `div` element an `id`, then use the Ajax call to put the `LastName` in the `.text()` of the `div`. For whatever reason, though, the `LastName` value, when sent back to the controller, is `null`.

The code below (as it should be written does.. well pretty much nothing. It will retrieve the name however it won't append it to the `DisplayFor` field. Also, when the form is submitted, the value for `LastName` on the model object is `null`. Like I mentioned above, if I give the `div` an `id` of `LastNameDisplay`, and include in the ajax `success` function `$('#LastNameDisplay').text(data)`, the last name will append itself to the `div` and be visible, however will still send a `null` value back to the controller.

This should be a very simply operation, and one that I complete on more than a couple other pages in this site. Any idea what's going wrong here?

**jQuery**

```
    $('#AccountNumber').on("blur", function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetLastName", "Agent")',
            data: { account: $(this).val() },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#LastName').val(data);
                $('#LastName').text(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

**HTML/Razor**

```
                    <div class="M-editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccountNumber)
                        <span class="req">@Html.Raw("*")</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="M-editor-field">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AccountNumber, new { maxlength = 9, title = "Enter 9 digit account number" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="M-editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
                    </div>
                    <div class="M-editor-field">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { style="display:none;" })
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
                    </div>
```

**Generated HTML**

```
<div class="M-editor-label">
    <label for="AccountNumber">Account Number</label>
    <span class="req">*</span>
</div>
<div class="M-editor-field">
    <input id="AccountNumber" maxlength="9" name="AccountNumber" title="Enter 9 digit account" type="text" value="019000109" />
</div>
<div class="M-editor-label">
    <label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
</div>
<div class="M-editor-field">
    <input id="LastName" name="LastName" style="display:none;" type="text" value="" />

</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the generated html?

Comment: Before or after the Ajax call?

Comment: I don't think it matters, try before.

Comment: Just posted, also included the `Razor` for the `AccountNumber` input as well.

Comment: LastName is input, you only need to $('#LastName').val(data)

Comment: @NealR you can store that `Value` to `HiddenField` and get that value in `Controller`.